# Formulário de contato em php não envia

Tags: php, formulário, wordpress

```
<?php

    $name     =   $_POST['name']; //pega os dados que foi digitado no ID name.
    $email    =   $_POST['email']; //pega os dados que foi digitado no ID email.
    $assunto  =   $_POST['assunto']; //pega os dados que foi digitado no ID Assunto.
    $mensagem  =   $_POST['mensagem']; //pega os dados que foi digitado no ID Mensagem.

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From: Site <comercial@meu_site.art.br>" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: comercial@meu_site.art.br" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();


/*abaixo contém os dados que serão enviados para o email
cadastrado para receber o formulário*/

       $corpo = "Formulario Enviado\n";
       $corpo .= "Nome: " . $name . "\n";
       $corpo .= "E-mail: " . $email . "\n";
       $corpo .= "Assunto: " . $assunto . "\n";
       $corpo .= "Mensagem: " . $mensagem . "\n";


       $email_to = 'comercial@meu_site.art.br'; //não esqueça de substituir este email pelo seu.

    $status = mail($email_to, $email, $corpo, $headers); //enviando o email.

    if($status) {
        echo "<script> alert('Mensagem enviada com sucesso!'); </script>"; //mensagem de form enviado com sucesso.
    }
    else {
        echo "<script alert('Falha ao enviar Mensagem.'); </script>"; //mensagem de erro no envio.
    }
    echo "<script> window.location.href = 'index.html'; </script>"; //mudar o site para redirecionar após o envio do form.
?>
```

Alguém pode me dizer ok tem de errado?

Comment: O que retorna de erro? Já conhece o Phpmailer?

Comment: da a informação que foi enviado com sucesso, mas o e-mail com as informações não chega. Ainda não conheço, até agora só fiz a introdução no PHP, vou começar a entrar nessa matéria no próximo semestre

Comment: Creio que `PHPMailer` não esteja na grade de algum curso, sugiro utiliza-lo, dê um olhada: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php

Comment: Se estiver testando em localhost não vai enviar o email mesmo, a menos que voce tenha feito as configurações necessárias para tal. O que a função `mail()` retorna é se foi executada sem erros, e não se o email foi enviado.

Comment: Então não tem como eu arrumar esse arquivo php para continuar usando ele?

Comment: Não consegui acessar o endereço http://meu_site.art.br/. Ele existe? Tem um servidor de email configurado pra ele?

Comment: Não Hugo isso é só para marcar o lugar do meu site. Eu consegui arrumar o PHP mas tem só um problema ainda. É que não consigo definir o remetente

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar o if direto na função mail pra ve se retorna algum erro.

```
       if (mail($email_to, $email, $corpo, $headers)){
            echo "<script> alert('Mensagem enviada com sucesso!'); </script>"; 
        }
        else {
            echo "<script alert('Falha ao enviar Mensagem.'); </script>"; 
        }
        echo "<script> window.location.href = 'index.html'; </script>";
```

Comment: Obrigado Alvaro, mas já arrumei o recebimento das informações, só estou com problemas para definir o remetente. Você sabe como fazer